# Can't edit question

Tags: support, editing

I don't see any link to edit [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2/can-an-expressive-power-of-the-query-language-maintained-through-left-join-if-di). I think it was the first question asked here, and I wanted to improve its grammar a bit, to make it more readable, but no edit link appears among the others.

Is that a bug? Maybe it's intentional for the first question ever? (I *can* edit all the others at the time of posting this question).

Comment: That was #2. I saw it disappear from the front page for a couple seconds, that may have something to do with it. I was about to suggest it had a pending edit, but we all have edit privs here.

Comment: @Kevin No, edit privilegess come at 500 rep in private beta. But there should be an `edit` button to suggest an edit, which I don't see either.

Comment: @Gilles Right, my bad. It probably is the pending edit then.

Comment: I actually edited the question, but due to lack of reputation (first seconds of private beta, yeah, that makes sense!), it is waiting for review. Maybe that's why you cannot edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question may only have one suggested edit active at a time.  If there is a suggested edit pending on the post, then other users will not be able to suggest a new edit, thus the link to do so will not appear.

I just went through and approved the pending suggested edits, so you should see a link now, and can improve the question further if you still wish to do so.

Comment: Yep. I can see the link now. In that case, it would be good to have some kind of message there, something like "this question has an edition waiting for approval".